# mail.app missing plug-in

Tags: macos, mail.app

Today I opened mail.app and my mail attachments showed up as "missing plug-in". I faced this issue before, at that time I quite the mail.app and opened again were fix the problem. Now that also not working.Please help me to fix this issue.

The Following are the content types in the mail:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" 
Content-Type: image/gif Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
Content-Type: text/html; 
Content-Type: image/jpeg   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

This is how my mail look like:

[image]

Comment: Might be something to to with java. See these pages for more help: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010062323063622   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2462812?start=45&tstart=0

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the message where you see "missing plug-in"?

Comment: @jaume if you give your mail id i can forward that mail.

Comment: guys i m still facing the issue.... plz help!!!

Comment: Since you have more than 10 reputation you can paste the screenshots directly to your question.

Comment: @jaume i have updated the question with screenshot..

Comment: Thanks, and when you press 'Save' next to 'Quick Look', which file gets saved to your Downloads folder? Could you post the *complete* file name? If you press 'Quick Look', do you see something? In that case, could you add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @jaume I have updated the screenshot, is there what ever you asked. Please help. thanks

Comment: Thanks. While that message is selected in Mail.app, could you please select *View>Message>Raw Source* and paste the contents of the new window to your answer?

Comment: @jaume I can not post that here since it contain all my official mail server configuration, etc. If you particularly tell about some tags, I can post it.

Comment: I fully understand, I just wanted to keep it simple... Please search 'Content-type:' and paste everything from the first match to the end of the message.

Comment: @jaume i have updated the question with `Content-type:`

Comment: Thanks, but I meant all text from the first 'Content-type' match to the end of the message. I need it because I suspect that the email message loads some content through the embedded HTML code that Mail.app can't display. What I know until now is that a JPEG is attached, but I can't believe that is the problem.

Comment: @ShineethHamza I believe Mail use WebKit as its render engine. So, it's web plugin for these content you need, not Mail plugin. And don't confuse Web plugins with Safari's extension, it's not. Web plugins are like Adobe Flash Player, which help Safari do Flash but does not appear under extension.

Comment: @ShineethHamza Plus, I cannot see "Missing plugin" in that screen shot.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat please rather than 100 more comments.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and solved it by going to:

```
System Preferences > Java > Security
```

and set the security level down to `medium`.

However I don't find this a very satisfying solution and I wonder why Mail requires Java to display images...

**Update:**

I assume it actually has nothing to do with Java itself but in some way with the plug-in loading. Maybe changing Java settings does something with the internet plugins... After all, now that my images do appear again, it has no further effect to change the java settings. The images will be displayed regardless of the java security settings. (So I set them back to `high`)

Maybe another solution is to have the privileges repaired or internet caches cleaned up...

Comment: Why does java affect jpeg inages?

Answer (score 0):

in general Mail plug-ins were saved in ~/Library/Mail.
The following steps are actable for OS 10.7 and later versions only.

The folder mentioned above is hidden and can be accessed by clicking "Go" in the Finder menu bar while pressing one of the alt-keys. 
In ~/Library/Mail drag all objects except the V2 folder to desktop and restart Mail.

Comment: The OP is not talking about a Mail.app plugin.

Comment: @praepersonal if I try this, will I loos my mails?

Comment: @praepersonal there is nothing other than V2 folder.

Answer (score -4):

I had this problem in OS X 10.8.5 and the solution was to quit and restart Mail.